# Explanation on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.RIGHTS

Tags: h2, information-schema

What is the purpose of this table? From it's name, could we assume that it lists all rights assigned to each user?

If we need to know what right are assigned to which user, should we look only this table? Or there is another table to read?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the purpose of this table?

It contains the list of rights of users and roles.

> Or there is another table to read?

Yes. You also need to know what roles are assigned to a user: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROLES`